# Angular 2 component not updating from observable subscription

Tags: meteor, angular, angular2-meteor

Using Angular 2 with Meteor, I have a component tree which uses a service to pass data between components and do the fetch and save stuff.

In the service,

```
   constructor() {
    this._contactId = new Subject<string>();
    this.contactid$ = this._contactId.asObservable();

  }
  // Service message commands
  SetContactId(id: string) {
      console.log("SetContactId "+id);
      this._contactId.next(id);
  }
```

This is used in a component to differentiate between a new contact or editing an existing one.

```
<div style="display:flex">
    Id: {{contactid}}
    <div style="flex:1 order:1" *ngIf="!contactid">
        <contact-new></contact-new>
    </div>
    <div style="flex:1 order:1" *ngIf="contactid">
        <contact-editor ></contact-editor>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the component subscription.

```
private contactid : string;

constructor (private _ContactService:ContactService) {


    ContactService.contactid$.subscribe(
        id => {
            //this.id = id;
            console.log('ContactEdit subscription '+id);
            this.contactid = id;
            this.updateId(id);
        } );
    }

    updateId(id) {
        console.log('updateid '+id)
        console.log(this.contactid);
    }
```

The contactid is set in two ways, and the results are not the same.

```
clickItem(contact) {
        console.log('clickItem');
        console.log(contact._id);
        this._contactService.SetContactId(contact._id);
    }
```

This is from a component with a list of contacts, and the click handler. It sets the id in the service, and the new/edit component works as expected.

The second way is in the new contact component constructor,

```
this.newContactForm.valueChanges
            .debounceTime(1000)
            .subscribe(newValue => this.readySave())

readySave() {
...
this._ContactService.newContact(q,true);
}
```

The newContact method is as follows, and when this is called the component doesn't update contactid.

```
newContact(data,setid : boolean) {
    let self = this;
    this.call('contacts.add',data,function (error,id) {
        if (!error) {
            console.log(id);
        if (setid) {
             self.SetContactId(id);
          }
          //self.loadRelations(id);
        }
      });
  }
```

The click handler works, but the delay from inserting the collection and returning seems to make the other scenario fail to update. If I tab or click out of the input the component updates. Console.log calls show the id being passed and set properly.

Any suggestions?

Edit: 
I built a skeleton of the app with only the relevant components. Oddly it works the first couple records then doesn't update after inserting the document, getting the id in the callback then the subscribe function assigning contactid in the component.

Another Edit: After beating this around a bit, I think I figured out where the problem exists, but not the solution.

The service is a MeteorComponent, Injectable(). The component comes with Angular2-meteor, and it wraps subscribe and call meteor methods. Specifically the call function seems to return a promise which then updates the value once the function has executed and returned a value on the server.

The update works if SetContactId is called from a click handler, but not if it is called by a Meteor method 'call' callback function within MeteorComponent.

Now to find a solution.

Comment: I don't get what the problem is. Can you create a Plunker that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: The contactid variable does not reactively update in the template.

Comment: `console.log('ContactEdit subscription '+id);` and `updateId(id) {...}` do print to the console?

Comment: Yes. The Id value is being set in the component in both situations. But in one scenario where the Id is acquired from the insert callback, the template does not get updated. If I tab out of the input, the template update occurs.

Comment: I don't see "acquired" somewhere in your code. Can you create a Plunker that allows to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I will do up an app to try to replicate the issue. There could be some issue between meteor, angular2,  or some version mismatch in the release candidate stack.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Hongbo_Miao, I've found the answer. It is necessary to wrap the SetContactId call in the Meteor.call callback in NgZone for it to update. It works as expected.

```
newContact(data,setid : boolean) {
    this.call('contacts.add',data,
        (error,id) => {
            this._ngZone.run(() => {
                console.log(id);
                if (setid) {
                    this.SetContactId(id);
                    console.log('newContact callback');
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: While the `autorun` method has a boolean flag if to run inside the NgZone, for some reason `call` does not. I was bitten by this once as well. Maybe worth a bug-report?

Comment: Ha, glad I can help!